# How do I get Android TabLayout to work even after adding support and design in gradle?

Tags: android

This is the error message that I get:

#### Gradle Console

```
HomeActivity.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
```

I have this on my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'`
```

Also,

```
compileSdkVersion 
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"


minSdkVersion 
targetSdkVersion 23`
```

#### HomeActivity.java

`public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
}
}`

#### activity_home2.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>`
```

What do I have to do to get this working? Most SO answer just asks me to put the support library which I think I did in gradle. Also, if I have to downgrade the compile version or the target version, I can. I don't need the latest and greatest feature for now.

I'm following a tutorial on tabs for Android [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/)

Thank you!

Comment: I fixed some of the formatting issues. However, your code is incomplete. In particular, you do not have any classes or methods for your Java code. Please correct this to give the context of the lines you have posted. Also, the code under "Home Activity.java" is missing a lot of stuff. Please fix it.

Comment: OK. But it may make the post very long.

Comment: Try cleaning your project and rebuild again

Comment: I'm not asking for all of your code. You should only add about 4 lines to the HomeActivity.java section.

Comment: That's a little better. You still need the `public class ...` line and the closing brace. You should remove the backticks and just indent every line four extra spaces. And you need to fix the lines of code so that they are actually correct.

Comment: Hey N J, I just tried cleaning and rebuilding it again but it's still showing me the same error. `Build` -> `Clean Project` and `Build` -> `Rebuild Project`

Comment: You should also show a complete build.gradle file. Or at least the the top-level sections which contain the pieces you posted.

Comment: Now to address your actual question: Do you have an `import` statement for `TabLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Towards the beginning of HomeActivity.java, you need the following line:

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
```

Comment: Thanks. Usually the IDE does it for me automatically. This time it adds this weird import that does nothing: `import static android.support.design.R.styleable.TabLayout;`

Comment: That import doesn't do nothing exactly. It's just the wrong `TabLayout`.